# Visual Studio - MVC Project creation App_Start folder automatic references to files from Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm just starting out with C# and the ASP.NET MVC. When you create a new MVC Application project in Visual Studio 2019, it generates an App_Start folder containing several classes (RouteConfig, BundleConfig, FilterConfig).  These files are referenced at the root of the project within Global.asax with the following:

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

However, there is NO using statement for the "App_Start" folder. These files are just "automatically" available.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

I would like to recreate this automatic availability with an MVC project I have that does NOT have these files in it.  I would like to manually create them, put them into a manually created "App_Start" folder and update my existing Global.asax to use "RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(...)".

Everytime I attempt to do this, I am forced to add a using statement to the "App_Start" folder in my Globals.asax.  Is there a way to take my existing project and make it work like the default project that Visual Studio creates when making an MVC Application project?

How does this automatic referencing work and where is there documentation on it?

Thank-you!

Comment: If two classes are in the same namespace, there is no need for a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same namespaces. Though they are in different folders, they are the same namespace, that is all that is needed.

Comment: Maybe you can click `√` to mark this as `Answer`.